# Evento ng-click do AngularJS não funciona quando configurado em um elemento vindo de uma requisição assíncrona

Tags: ajax, angularjs, eventos

Tenho uma página chamada listaDT.php que contém um DataTable (https://www.datatables.net/). Utilizei a interface do plugin DataTable para carregar dinamicamente o conteúdo do DataTable. A última coluna da tabela contém apenas checkboxes. Eu quero que estes checkboxs disparem o evento $scope.atualizarPedido() que implementei no controller OpcoesCtrl, mas não consigo, nada é exibido no console da caixa de ferramentas do browser, talvez porque os checkboxes estão sendo carregados dinamicamente, pois quando utilizo um elemento da própria página listaDT.php como trigger do evento $scope.atualizarPedido() minha implementação funciona como esperado.

Observação: os checkboxes estão dentro do contexto do controller OpcoesCtrl.

Pergunta: como utilizar os checkboxes para disparar o evento em questão?

Answer (score 2):

O AngularJS compila seu template Angular (o que sem o Angular seria HTML estático) quando a página é carregada no navegador. É nesse momento que el reconhece as diretivas e faz as ligações internas para ouvir eventos em elementos que contenham diretivas.

Se você adiciona elementos à página posteriormente, isso vai ser "texto morto" - o Angular não vai "ver" nenhuma diretiva lá.

Execute "$compile" nos trechos de HTML que você carrega/constrói dinâmicamente, antes de adiciona-los à página - isso fara com que o ângular "enxergue" as diretivas lá,. Só que  não testei aqui como ficaria o escopo para isso, já que você tem que executar o $compile nos elementos antes de adiciona-los à sua posição final - é possível que isso não funcione.

Se tudo o mais falhar, use o bom e velho "onclick" do javascript nos elementos que você cria dinamicamente.

Comment: Obrigado. Sua explicação foi bastante didática. Vou testar o "$compile" e mais tarde volto com o resultado.